# Angular 4 + primeng : pass HTML content from a component to another

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng, primeng-datatable, angular2-ngcontent

I want to add some server-side pagination functions to the primeng datatable (p-datatable) in multiple places so I declared a new component "pagin-datatable.component" with the functions and behavior I need.

So **pagin-datatable.component.html** (template) comes with :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="value" 
  resizableColumns="true" 
  scrollable="true" 
  scrollWidth="100%" 
  [(rows)]="this.gridOptions.rows" 
  [paginator]="true" 
  [lazy]="true" 
  [totalRecords]="nbTotal" 
  (onFilter)="filtrage($event)"
  (onPage)="pagination($event)" 
  (onSort)="tri($event)" 
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="rowsPerPageOptions" >
  /* There should be the p-columns */
</p-dataTable>
```

I want my p-columns still be declared in my **main.component.html** like :

```
<pagin-datatable [value]="partenaires" (pagin)="refresh($event)" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20,40]">
        <p-column sortable="true" [filter]="true" field="aField"     header="A HEADER"></p-column>
        /* And so it goes for every other p-columns */
 </pagin-datatable>
```

My question is the following : how do I tell my pagin-component to let the p-datatable treat the content sent into the component tags ?

> After the answer below:

Found this article to fix the primeng problem : github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1215.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use in **pagin-datatable.component.html** like this

```
    <p-dataTable [value]="value" 
  resizableColumns="true" 
  scrollable="true" 
  scrollWidth="100%" 
  [(rows)]="this.gridOptions.rows" 
  [paginator]="true" 
  [lazy]="true" 
  [totalRecords]="nbTotal" 
  (onFilter)="filtrage($event)"
  (onPage)="pagination($event)" 
  (onSort)="tri($event)" 
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="rowsPerPageOptions" >
  /* There should be the p-columns */
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</p-dataTable>
```

and in your **main.component.html** you can warp your column in **pagin-datatable**  as you want.

Comment: Completely forgot this major feature of Angular... thanks. However the lifecycle prevent the p-columns to be recovered by the table. Found this article (by typing ng-content + primeng) to fix the problem : https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1215. Works perfectly !